# impossible import of a module from github

Tags: python, pip, module

i've made a module that've post on github,
i've set the setup.py and the _*init*_.py as it's needed for pip to recognise it.
the pip install seems to work fine.

```bash
pip install git+https://github.com/loictonneau75/spellcheck.git
```

but when I write the import line

```py
import spellcheck
```

it doesn't find the module

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/loictonneau/Desktop/try/rry.py", line 1, in <module>
    import spellcheck
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spellcheck'
```

i've check if the module was indeed install and it is

```bash
pip show spellcheck
Name: spellcheck
Version: 0.0.1
Summary: SpellCheck is a Python library designed to check and correct spelling errors in texts across multiple language
#and more...
```

i've try install unistall several time,
change the name in the setup.py of the module
where am I wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guys from discord help me here's the problem i had :

```
it looks like vscode is using the global 3.12 interpreter rather than the venv you installed your package to
```

Answer (score 0):

The pip name and import name can be different. In this case the module name is case sensitive and spelled `SpellCheck` because of the directory it's in. You got it right in the `__main__.py` file:

```
from SpellCheck.spellcheck import SpellCheck
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os

if __name__ == "__main__":
    load_dotenv()
    sp = SpellCheck(os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY"),"fr")
    print(sp("coocou"))
```

To rename the import, just rename the directory `SpellCheck` to `spellcheck`, and update the imports as necessary.

Comment: i've try all combinaison of upper and lower letter it's not the problem

Comment: @loictonneau Just to be clear, you tried `from SpellCheck.spellcheck import SpellCheck` and got `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named SpellCheck`?